# What is the program doing

Tags: java

This program is to find the no. of input which is divisible by k.
however I got a program that does this but can't understand what is the code marked `// <--` doing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    String s = br.readLine();// <--
    int end = s.indexOf(' ');// <--
    int n = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, end));// <--
    int k = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(end+1));// <--

    int count = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
        if (Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())%k == 0){
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking up the Integer.parseInt method?

Comment: it is running absolutely fine.. I just want to know that what exactly the code in the comment is doing...

Comment: This will do nothing  because there is a compile error. you have comment out the variable k . so compiler gives you an error saying symbol can't be found

Comment: program finds positions of `' '` character, and get two bits before and after, then converts them to integers

Comment: @Pshemo: I have just commented so that it gets highlighted regarding the code's working that I want to know.. if u remove the comment it will work fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explained code with comments:

```
public class division {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String s = br.readLine(); //reads a line from the console (user has to enter with keyboard and then push [ENTER])
        int end = s.indexOf(' '); //finds the index of the first space and writes it into "end"
        int n = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, end)); //parses an int from the given user input. stops at the first space (because of "end")
        int k = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(end + 1)); //parses an int from the given user input. starts after the first space (because of "end")

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()) % k == 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

### Demo input:

1. Compile and run the program
2. Enter the following string `3 4`and then push [ENTER] (the first digit determines how often you want to make the devision check, the second digit determines which number you want to get checked)
3. Enter the following string `8 12 7`and then push [ENTER] (these are the numbers you want to check)
4. You get as result in the console `2` (because two numbers (`8` & `12`) were divisible by `4`)

Comment: thanks Robert.. Can you write the same code using Scanner to read the input.

Comment: It should be possible to just use Scanner as a substitute for the BufferedReader. So just initialize it `input = new Scanner(System.in);` and get the console input with `input.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

```
 String s = br.readLine();// reads the inputstream

    int end = s.indexOf(' '); //make a integer variable and initialize it with the index of  first space in string
    int n = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, end)); // performs substring operation and this line stops at the first space 
    int k = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(end+1));*/ performs substring operation and stops at after the first space
```

Answer (score 0):

While running your program,you must be passing your "n" and "k" separated by a (" ")space on console.
what your program does is it takes it as a complete string from console.
Now your commented code splits this string and parses it into integer.
this can also be achieved by

```
String[] nums = br.readLine().split(" ");
int n = Integer.parseInt(nums[0]);
int k = Integer.parseInt(nums[1]);
```